# how to pass user data ( name, adress, etc ) from shipping step to my custom step?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need to show user information on my custom step, i tried to use quote object which stores this information, but i can't understand how to pass it only when information is already set to quote, how to trigger function only after navigation to my custom step.
How to check that user is navigated to my custom step to call a function which will be get data from quote?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check in the file

```
Magento_Checkout\js\view\progress-bar.js
```

here navigateTo function is there, where you can put your log and check you are on your custom step or not